# VBA SeleniumDriver Issue: Browser Not Returning to UserForm After Subroutine Completion

Tags: selenium-webdriver, userform, vba7

I am using a VBA SeleniumDriver and SeleniumElement API. First, we fill in some information in the UserForm. After that, it launches Edge, and as per the condition, it fills in some information on the site. However, when the subroutine ends, the browser closes automatically. It should, according to the condition, go back to the UserForm. If anyone knows how to solve this problem, please help me.

I have searched and tried for 6 hours but i can not solve the probelm. When I use the same process through Selenium installed in the system, it works fine according to the condition. However, in VBA with the Selenium API, it does not work.

NOTE:- If you want code of VBA Seleium API, click on below link, which i am using.
https://github.com/sdkn104/VBA-Selenium.git

Comment: No. Add a minimal, reproducible example to your question.